# My Bunn coffeemaker has started overflowing at the funnel

Tags: equipment

We recently moved to Indiana from Colorado.  Our new house in Indiana has a water softener and I have read that soft water can cause Bunns to overflow.  I have not read anything about how this is solved.  I have pulled the nozzle and it was not clogged.  Is it just a matter of getting a different nozzle?  If so, what nozzle do I go with?  Thanks.

Comment: Come over to [coffee.se] and ask there instead! :)

Comment: @hoc_age cross site duplicates within the network are not allowed. Scott, you are welcome to ask coffee-related questions on the sister site hoc_age suggested, but please choose one site for each question, don't repeat it on both sites.

Comment: @rumtscho - I think the question was only posted here. Indeed, I certainly was *not* suggesting duplication (hence "instead") -- I should have been more clear. I'm just trying to help the nascent [coffee.se] site get on-point questions! (Come one, come all! ;-)

Comment: @hoc_age good point. I wanted to make sure the OP understands this is not an invitation to ask in both places. Inviting users to join Coffee is OK with me, I wish you luck extending your community.

Comment: @rumtscho - Agreed! Thanks for the information, and [recommendation to not migrate if on-topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/262760) at the original post site. And thanks for the well-wishes! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the soft water is helping the coffee "bloom" (and eventually overflow past the top of the basket) more than when you were using harder/more mineralized water. All else held equal, there's a few things to try to solve the concern, as one or a combination of the following may work.

## Try:

1. ...reducing the amount of water you place in the tank, and expect smaller/less servings.
2. ...putting in less coffee in the basket, balancing the risk of getting "watered-down" coffee (see #1 above).
3. ...using/buying coarse ground coffee instead of the fine powder (for the reasons below)

## Now if you grind the beans yourself, also try:

3. ...using a burr grinder (instead of a blade-type) for more consistent coffee size, as the fines from using a blade grinder may be clogging your mesh/paper filter (not the nozzle!)
4. ...grinding the coffee a little bit coarser to give more space for the water to run through.

Hope this helps.